# Connect to IP in application layer, Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http, networking, air

I'm working on a project about "controlling embedded system by smartphones via wifi",

I developed my app on adobe Air, and built my system on PIC microcontroller to accept connections on application layer (Http), the ip address is 192.168.20.60:80(responsed when browsing from web browsers).

Instead of using sockets to connect through port 80, I used urlloader to read HTML pages (urlrequest("x.com")).
But when I tried to connect to ip address IOexception appears, 
here's the code:

```
var PicPage:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
PicPage.load(new URLRequest("192.168.20.60")); //worked using DNS
lgn.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,ff);
    function ff(e:Event):void{
        var s:String=e.target.data;
        trace(s);
        }
```

Comment: Try with with "http://" and specify port :80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pixel Elephant said, You need to have http:// in front of the IP you are trying to contact. You don't need to specify port 80 though.

Try the following code:

```
var PicPage:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
PicPage.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
PicPage.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);

PicPage.load(new URLRequest("http://192.168.20.60/"));

protected function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var s:String = e.target.data;
    trace(s)    
}
protected function onError(e:Event):void {
    // Handle the error in any way you'd like
}
```

I've used this code ( and variations of it ) multiple times myself and it has served me well.

Comment: cool, thnx hazard, i tried "http" before but for some reasons it didn't work. amazing